# Why does panels on line 14 have a red squiggle and how can I fix it?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm writing in Typescript for the first time with React and my getAllPanels function line 14 has a red squiggle in my return under the word panels. When I hover over it, it says **Property 'panels' does not exist on type 'PanelData[]'.ts(2339)**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';
import PanelList, { PanelData } from './components/PanelList';

const kBaseURLPanels = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/panels/';

const getAllPanels = () => {
  return axios
    .get<PanelData[]>(kBaseURLPanels)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res)
      return res.data.panels.map(convertPanelFromAPI)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("Error fetching panels:", err);
      return [];
    });
};

const convertPanelFromAPI = (apiPanel: { id: number; name: string; organ_id: number; }) => {
  const { id, name, organ_id } = apiPanel;
  const newPanel = { id, name, organID: organ_id };
  return newPanel;
};

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [panelData, setPanelData] = useState<PanelData[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllPanels().then((panels) => {
      console.log("Fetched panels:", panels);
      setPanelData(panels);
    });
  }, []);

  console.log("panelData in App:", panelData);

  return (
    <div>
      <PanelList panelData={panelData} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I tried googling and finding similar questions, the workaround seems to be an interface to me but I'm not sure. The data is coming from a .csv file in the backend that's in Python/Django.

Answer (score 0):

By using `.get<PanelData[]>`, you're telling Typescript that `res.data` will be of type `PanelData[]`. It seems like you're really expecting `get` to return some sort of object that has a property `panels` of type `PanelData[]`, not simply an array of `PanelData`.

Comment: Thank you! How would I fix this?

Comment: @user22248976 What do you expect `get()` to return? You need to define a type for that and use it in the `<>`.

Comment: This is what it's returning (from the console) and I'm trying to get the arrays. 
(data.panels)

data
: 
panels
: 
Array(16)
0
: 
{id: 1, name: 'Liver Function Panel', organ_id: 1}
1
: 
{id: 2, name: 'Basic Metabolic Panel', organ_id: 2}
2
: 
{id: 3, name: 'CBC/Differential', organ_id: 5}
3
: 
{id: 4, name: 'Lipid Panel', organ_id: 3}

Comment: But what does `data` look like in terms of type? That's what you need to use in `.get<...>`

Comment: Good to hear, please accept my answer if it helped you!

Comment: Why has this answer not been marked as accepted?